# How to compute differences in intercept and slope in linear mixed effect regression?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, mixed-models

I am trying to perform a simple linear mixed effect regression for the day of green-up in the Arctic.

I would like to find the effect that weather has on the green-up day within each region (16 different regions pan-Arctic), and if the green-up day differs significantly (intercept) between the different regions (ANOVA), and which region then actually differs (posthoc test).

My data, after scaling to center, is as follows:

```
library(readr)
library(blme)
data <- read_csv("data.csv")
data.sc <- data.frame(scale(data))
head(data.sc)
     regions      year    greenup          V1         V2          V3        V4          V5       V6            V7         V8       V9        V10
1          1 -1.687957  0.9336382  0.85187965 0.71761508  3.16360255 1.6670476 -0.68640856 -0.655334953 -1.799065  1.5577978 3.0125643 -0.5009276
2          1 -1.601395  0.2370278 -0.30385233 0.59926804  0.04203437 1.3281044 -0.62391808 -0.592095987 -1.590912  0.6735797 1.2016789 -0.5955858
3          2 -1.514833  0.8030237 -0.05341494 0.05770376 -0.03230812 0.4116001 -0.34697632 -0.311837094 -1.428521  0.2459790 0.7906408 -0.7097304
4          2 -1.428272 -0.1548155 -0.52504749 0.21499928 -0.53588809 1.3991222 -0.70552873 -0.674684140 -1.491065 -0.5336937 0.1615725 -0.6405863
5          3 -1.341710  0.4111804 -0.55526813 0.41495915 -0.28220429 1.0430792 -0.69965688 -0.668741960 -1.440828 -0.1372223 0.3667727 -0.8735882
6          3 -1.255148  1.7717476  0.37503107 0.49582150  3.25563398 1.1052932 -0.06417199 -0.005461234 -1.859388  1.6666640 3.6155112 -0.6626455
```

I, therefore, perform a linear mixed model using the Bayesian package in R (`blme`) to avoid the `boundary (singular)` warning. Here, I make sure I get the global intercept and slope but also the deviation for each of these regions. Hence, my model looks as follows:

```
reg <- blmer(greenup ~ V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8+(1+V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8|regions), data = pre.sc, REML = F)
ranef(reg)

   (Intercept)           V1          V2          V3          V4           V5          V6        V7          V8
1   -1.5088397 -0.678780774 -0.28176494  0.03297057  0.14762373  0.135628050  0.03870133 -0.16881483  0.01049209
2    1.4277155  0.002705333  0.63878199  0.04527960 -0.29932021 -0.092542944 -0.05871342  0.12192872  0.16659908
3   -1.1971171 -0.643673842 -0.36725321 -0.00437876  0.09999908 -0.195088268  0.02960333 -0.07320157  0.21971584
4   -1.8725315 -0.785756089 -0.38010681 -0.02575994  0.28474568  0.840094435 -0.13247112 -0.05102267 -0.77963082
5    1.0132713 -0.429509626 -0.31425681  0.29430628 -0.19690372  0.282548814  0.39303350 -0.12090616  0.69670371
6   -2.4881956 -1.692458471 -0.09449177  0.01172166  0.06284188 -0.844244673  0.79118303 -0.34123995  1.04264827
7    3.1058386  0.826832058  1.11178582  0.02043532 -0.47408031 -0.338428604 -0.33133031  0.31261663  0.10124955
8    1.9322901  3.317059011 -0.30085324 -0.22707802  0.28574031 -0.569026041 -0.42553220  0.17865665 -0.47420030
9   -1.2204600 -2.438705399  1.87732120 -0.07449666 -0.38793703  0.188712028 -0.38356492  0.11440041 -0.52707496
10   2.0227413  1.395666163  0.67593119 -0.14830203 -0.16997007 -0.385349601 -0.34510500  0.26727338 -0.24816029
11  -1.9223249 -0.767426078 -0.23096931 -0.10032745  0.14049704  0.003901228  0.01478041 -0.07175487 -0.12908571
12   0.0149983 -0.492942263 -0.40391390  0.16250771 -0.06522357  0.566016764  0.35380727 -0.11917404  0.19111680
13  -0.7919515 -0.731003237 -0.34630359  0.17115953  0.10735851  0.940255206 -0.07730108 -0.11185924 -0.37309296
14   4.7216459  4.388771043 -1.08519982  0.01923765  0.10673146 -0.205195431 -0.03391026  0.21661697  0.12766651
15   0.1163438 -0.623755530 -0.09248300  0.15112399 -0.08205915  0.193081476  0.03723803 -0.03449855  0.24479648
16  -3.3534245 -0.647022299 -0.40622380 -0.32839946  0.43995636 -0.520362438  0.12958139 -0.11902088 -0.26974330
```

How do I proceed to investigate how the intercept (greenup day) differs between the random effect (regions)?
How do I look into, how the variables may have different interaction/influence on the greenup day too?

Answer (score 0):

This may end up being better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Probably the easiest way to extract the random effects values with confidence intervals (**see caveats below**) is

```r
library(broom.mixed)
tt <- (tidy(reg, effects = "ran_vals", conf.int = TRUE)
   |> dplyr::filter(term == "(Intercept)") 
   |> dplyr::select(level, estimate, conf.low, conf.high)
)
```

This is (obviously) just looking at the intercept term.

You can look at the magnitudes of the variances of the different random effect components and compare their magnitudes.

If you `lattice::dotplot(ranef(reg))` you will see all random-effects conditional modes, with their conditional standard deviations, with regions ordered by their intercept. You might want ``lattice::dotplot(ranef(reg), scales = "free")` instead.

If you know ggplot you can use the output of `tidy` above to plot more flexibly.

Formal testing is more difficult.

You could fit a model without the intercept variation:

```r
reduced <- update(reg, . ~
   V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8+(0 + V1+V2+V3+V4+V5+V6+V7+V8|regions))
anova(reduced, reg)
```

- This won't work sensibly if any of your covariates is a factor (removing the intercept will just reparameterize the model, not actually drop the intercept variation)
- I would not be surprised if the variation in all of the other effects could compensate for the restriction that the intercept isn't allowed to vary
- You could do this for any of the random-effects terms.

The idea of post-hoc testing to figure out *which* of the regions differs significantly in its intercept is right out the window, for theoretical reasons: when you estimate variation as a random effect, the predicted values for individual levels (called "best linear unbiased predictors" [BLUPs] or "conditional modes") are no longer parameter estimates in the formal sense, with sampling distributions, p-values, etc.. In the frequentist world, this is one of the things you sacrifice by using a random effect.